# How to define a data type for holding string and numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, structure, frequency

C structure question

I have a list of words and their corresponding frequencies:

```
word 10
the 50
and 35
overflow 90
```

How should I hold this data in a structure? Should I use a two dimensional array? I should also note I have to sort them by their frequency, so I'm thinking an array of some sort then apply qsort, but I need to preserve the integers so if I use a char array I have to do back and forth casting

Comment: are the specific words going to change?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a struct:

```
struct WordInfo {
    char *word;
    int frequency;
};
```

Then you can make an array of these structs:

```
struct WordInfo words[128]; // whatever
```

And finally write a comparator function like this:

```
int word_compare(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    struct WordInfo *s1 = p1;
    struct WordInfo *s2 = p2;
    return s1->frequency - s2->frequency;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the maximum number of characters for the string which you are going to handle means use array and int data type inside a structure.

```
typded struct _data
{
   char word[MAX_CHARS];
   int freq;
}DATA;
...

DATA *d = malloc(sizeof(DATA) * n);
```

If you dont know the max characters of `word` go for pointer charater `char *word;`. In this case memory allocation will happen for each entry which will affect the performance and it will cause more fragmentation.

Its better to allocate a chunk of memory once rather than allocating small memory for `n` times.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have an array of std::pair

Then you can run whatever sorting algorithm you want to sort the array based on the second element.
For example you will have:

std::pair myArray[size];

Answer (score 0):

Define a structure type, something like

```
struct wordAndFrequency
{
  char *word;
  int count;
};
```

then take an array of `struct wordAndFrequency` and `qsort` that.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct Dict {
  char *word;
  int frequency;
} Dictionary;
```

Now create array of this structure object and use it as hashmap. When you come across a word, see if this word is there, increment the counter else add this word with count as 1.

```
 Dictionary *dictionary=(Dictionary*)malloc(sizeof(Dictionary)*SIZE);
```